# time.sleep() in a node

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node where I need to wait for a specific amount of time. Can I just use time.sleep() in python or do I need something else?
Thanks,
luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233331/time.sleep()-in-a-node/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2016-04-30

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should definitely NOT use `time.sleep()`

The ROS way of doing this is:

```
rate = rospy.Rate(1) # 1 Hz
# Do stuff, maybe in a while loop
rate.sleep() # Sleeps for 1/rate sec
```

Or the similar:

```
rospy.sleep(1) # Sleeps for 1 sec
```

In both cases, you'll ofc need to `import rospy`

Here's the API documentation: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rospy/html/rospy.rostime-module.html

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-04-30**:
I only want to delay once, not repeatedly. How would I implement that?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-30**:
It's the second code snippet above: `rospy.sleep(1) # Sleeps for 1 sec`  Adapt it to how many seconds you want to delay.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-01**:
@luketheduke, if my answer was correct / helpful, please "mark it as correct" by clicking on the checkmark button to its left. It will help people who read this question in the future. Thanks.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-05-30**:
What is the benefit of using `rospy.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`?  Is it just that it is [interruptible](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates)?

**Comment by [marko525](https://answers.ros.org/users/101067/marko525/) on 2022-04-29**:
+1 on @Rufus question comment. It's a very strong `NOT`, without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another option is using

```
ros::Duration(1.0).sleep()  // Sleep for one second
```

while `Rate` requires the sleep duration in Hz (1/s), `Duration` requires the sleep time in seconds. Typically, `Rate` is used inside loops, while `Duration` is the better choice when the sleeping occurs just once.

---

Originally posted by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) with karma: 635 on 2019-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2