# Using time.sleep() in ROS2 Nodes

Tags: ros2, node

I want to delay a ROS2 Node, This [answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/73680/time-sleep-in-a-node) is given respect to ROS1:

Whats the equivalent in ROS2. A quick on the fly time.sleep() but for ROS because I know time.sleep() in ros is a nono.

Answer (score 1):

For ROS 2 node functionality that should run at fixed time intervals, I use a callback that runs on a timer.

The simple C++ publisher tutorial is an example:

https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#write-the-publisher-node

Here's an example in Python from:

https://github.com/mikeferguson/ros2_cookbook/blob/main/rclpy/time.md#timers

```py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

class MyNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("my_node")

        # Create a timer that fires every quarter second
        timer_period = 0.25
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        self.get_logger().info("timer has fired")
```

> I know time.sleep() in ros is a nono.

You can use `rate.sleep()` from the cookbook above if you need a single or variable delay and you're worried about a sleep call blocking other node functionality. Note the need to inform the thread about the `rclpy.spin` function if you want `rate.sleep()` to be nonblocking.

Comment: If I use Node A to make a request to Node B, will rate.sleep() in Node B pause the flow in main thread such that Node A waits until Node B completes finishes its rate.sleep().  (using a future or whatever the condition is)?